# static in my video sound

Tags: audio, noise, cable

I am getting static sound on my video playback. I have my computer and camcorder going into a manual switcher and out of the switcher to a monitor on the wall. The static occurs when I have my HDMI cable from my computer plugged into the switcher. Whenever I unplug the HDMI cable from the computer or turn the computer off the static stops. All the cables are HDMI. Please help.

Comment: Check for ground loops on all the gear in the chain. Do they all plug into the same outlet? Putting everything on the same power strip going to a single outlet may solve this as long as the outlet can handle the peak load.

Comment: Ground loops more often cause hum, in my experience, but certainly worth checking. I'd also try simply connections -- bypass the switcher and just feed source to amp to speaker -- to try to isolate the problem; it may be as simple as a bad cable.